# cut slice of file based on time when lines are written

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, date

i have a process running always with logging file could reach up to 5 giga, sometime i have to take slice of this log based on interval of time (usually i used dd).
is there any command in linux to take the slice of log based on time interval?

PS:there is no time stamp in most of lines within this log.

Comment: What do you mean of `dd`?

Comment: Command dd used to take slices but using it based on number of lines or blocks (could not find a way to use it base on time.)
So have to know from which line to which line have to take the slice and this method take some time:
example:
dd if=o.log  of=d.log skip=47615 count=50 bs=100

Comment: You cannot do this without altering your logging system in some way: you'll need time stamps… there's no way to get the time when a line was written out of a file (at least in terms of stock system support).  Your system doesn't even care what exactly a line is…

Comment: What does your log format look like? Does it have dates at the beginning of each line, in which format? (If there are no dates in your log itself, then it's impossible to tell: the system doesn't keep track of when each byte was written.)

Comment: :( here is the problem, there is no time stamps at the beginning of each line only we have like transaction ID (10 digits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is not a command that allow you to do (like suggested by Wiese), why don't you create an external index of your file?

Just the idea : you can do a script that run forever (or almost see notes below), and give the time intervals to create the index.

```
PIDofThisInstance=$$
# ... you code for the header, checks... 
while true  ; do
  # This is the core of your cycle
    sync   # Maybe
    CurrentSize=`ls -s $MyFile  | awk '{print $1} ' `
    CurrentTime=`date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
    echo $CurrentTime $CurrentSize >> $Log_Of_My_Log_File
    sleep $TimeToSleep
  # if (exit-condition)
  # then
  #    break           #Exit from the infinite loop.
  # fi
done
```

After you can do another script that given the starting/ending date/time answers you with starting/ending sizes. From that numbers you can cut your file.

You said it is a huge file. So I do not suggest you to do with *linenumbers* and
maybe `head MyFile.log -n xxx | tail -n yyy`. It will be long. Better to work with size.

Notes:

- If this is a log with a formatted output (even if unknown by you) it's always possible that it exists some analysis tool from the developer company/programmer. It's possible it will came out even after years. IMHO better do not touch that format and create a separate file.
- Write in your script parameter like current PID (in case you need to kill by hands), the name of file (object of the logging), if you know the PID of the program that generates the log...
- The cycle can be forever or end if you have a condition like: the the PID of the program that generate the log doesn't exist anymore, the file doesn't exist anymore, the actual size is littler than the old one (you move the file or restart the log you need to restart the indexing).
- If you keep in memory the $LastSize you can decide to avoid to print lines in the "log of the log" when is not needed, or stop after a long time with no activity (or modify dynamically the time interval...)